# OSGi bundle not getting deployed in WSO2 esb

Tags: osgi, bundle, esb

I've installed WSO2 esb (v 4.6) on my machine.
I've created a sample HelloWorld project. This project has an interface, an impl class. Also it has an Activator that implements BundleActivator from OSGi framework.
I've put in a simple sysout commands in the start() and stop() methods of this activator.

I've then modified my pom.xml to change the packaging as "bundle".
Also added maven-bundle-plugin with all the necessary instructions to package my project as an OSGi bundle.

Just to ensure that my bundle has been packaged correctly, I deployed it on Eclipse provided Equinox OSGI container and on start/stop of bundle I can see the sysouts on the osgi console.
This hopefully confirms that my bundle is proper.

Now I want to deploy this bundle on WSO2 carbon framework.
So I placed my bundle (the .jar file) under "C:\Program Files\wso2esb-4.6.0\repository\components\plugins" path and then launched the ESB using below command:

wso2server.bat -DosgiConsole

This gave me the osgi> prompt. On doing ss on the osgi command prompt, I do get a list of bundles that were started by the WSO2's carbon framework. However, nowhere I can see the my bundle in the list.
I also did a check in the log folder (C:\Program Files\wso2esb-4.6.0\repository\log) to see if there was any sysout from the "start" method of my BundleActivator. However I couldn't find any in all of the log files present under this folder.

I would like to know if I'm missing out anything here in order to get my bundle activated by the WSO2 carbon framework ?

If there is a way I can attach my bundle in this forum then let me know so that I can attach it so that I can know from your end if the bundle packaging is correct or not.

Many thanks in advance and Best Regards
LB

---

Thanks for the replies; indeed placing the bundle in "dropins" folder resolved the issue.

My next step is to view this bundle under the "features" tab of management console.
For that, I understand, the bundle needs to be deployed on a repository.

On the management console, I see two radio buttons (under Repository Management tab) for defining repository uri viz., "URL" and "Local".
I first chose the "local" radio option and gave the absolute file path of the folder where my bundle was placed on my file system. However it prompted with an error message of invalid path.
I'm now planning to place this bundle under a svn repository and will then give that path.
Before I do that, I would like to know
1) Does the code logic behind "features" functionality look for a specific directory structure ? If yes, can someone pls let me know what should be that structure ?
2) Just placing the bundle in the repository under a specific directory structure (if any) will make the bundle appear in the "features" link (i.e., after I select the configured repository uri from drop-down and click on "Find Features" button) OR there is more ground work that needs to be done ?
My objective is to have my bundle appear as a "feature".

Many thanks again in advance for all the suggestions.

Best Regards
LB

Answer (score 1):

Deploy your jar in `repository\components\dropins` instead of repository\components\plugins. That is where you should deploy custom bundles.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy jar file in to /repository/components/lib directory and restart the server. After restart the esb, check the jar in /repository/components/dropins to verify that the ESB take it successfully.

The best practice is, copy the jar file in to /repository/components/lib and  need to restart since wso2-esb not recommend for hot deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question on making your bundle appear as a feature in the Feature Management UI:

First you need to create a feature including your bundle. Then you need to follow the steps given in the following post.
http://blog.kasunbg.org/2013/04/generating-wso2-p2-repo-for-features.html